# Using the transparency function on NirCMD.exe, I made an opacity effect but the command prompt disappear after execution

Tags: batch-file

I'm using the transparency function found in NirCMD, a plugin utility for the commmand line. A link to download and a guide is here:http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html. I have the following code for an opacity effect:

```
:FADE
FOR /L %%G IN (100,1,256) DO (
   nircmd.exe win trans ititle "cmd" %%G
)
GOTO :EOF
```

I run it by calling it:

```
CALL :FADE
echo.
echo.
echo ÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛ
echo.
echo.
echo GAME  
echo.
echo.
echo.                          
echo Play (a)       
echo.
echo.
echo Highscore (b) 
echo.
echo.
echo Credits (c)
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛ
```

However, after the opacity effect finishes, the command prompt completely disappears. Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Thanks :)

Comment: Open a command prompt and run the script from there instead of double-clicking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, you are naming it `:FADE` which suggests becoming gradually more transparent.

The most transparent value is `0` and the least transparent, `255`, *(most opaque)*. For this reason and for easy understanding you should reverse the numbers in your `For` loop to start with the least transparent value, *(highest number)*, step in negative increments, and stop at your most transparent value, *(lowest number)*.

If you use a known title, using the `Title` command, you could then use `nircmd`'s `title` instead of `intitle` or `etitle` to find it.

Because the time taken to loop through each step is very quick a delay would be wise in between each. `Timeout` could be used, however `1` second delays between each iteration is far too much for a reasonable fade type effect, so I have decided to use `PathPing` instead.

It is also suggested that you use the `Start` command with its `/B` option, to both allow the process to run without affecting the loop iterations and to not open new individual windows.

Finally, my answer uses the console version of `nircmd.exe`, `nircmdc.exe`. It is supposed to be identical in use; the difference being that output messages are provided to the console as opposed to GUI boxes, *(although, in this case there shouldn't be any output)*.

Here's the example code:

```bat
@Echo Off
Title Fade
For /L %%A In (255,-15,105) Do Start "" /B nircmdc win trans title "Fade" %%A & PathPing 127.0.0.1 -n -q 1 -p 225 >Nul
```

*Feel free to adjust the step increment, `-15`, and wait period, `225` to achieve the effect you require.*

---

If you want to perform the opposite function, i.e. increase opacity, then you'd use this structure:

```bat
@Echo Off
Title Opacate
For /L %%A In (105,15,255) Do Start "" /B nircmdc win trans title "Opacate" %%A & PathPing 127.0.0.1 -n -q 1 -p 225 >Nul
```

*Feel free to adjust the step increment, `15`, and wait period, `225` to achieve the effect you require.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I put in the first part of your code, and it works perfectly. However, I have the same problem. As soon as it stops fading, the command prompt window immediately disappears, along with the Notepad window. Any ideas why?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I checked again and it works perfectly now. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The maximum of transparent is 255, so for 100% transparency, you have to change 256 to 255.
The reason for this is because when it touch over the limit, the number will go back to 0, and that why the window is disappear after the run.